# Matplotlib figure coordinates don't seem correct

Tags: matplotlib, coordinates, annotate

As per the block of code below, using `ax.annotate()` it appears that the outer extents of the Figure object are not properly captured by `figure fraction`. I would expect the arrows to point right to the very corners of the plot, which as per **first plot** they do not.

Also when the figure plot is created without any of the annotations, it is not the same size - see **second plot**. The annotations I've used should not change the figure size. I'm using info from this [Matplotlib page](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/text_labels_and_annotations/annotation_demo.html).

Anyone able to explain these oddities?

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.axis([0, 10, 0, 10])
bbox_args = dict(boxstyle="round, pad=0.3", fc="w", ec='red', alpha=0.5)
arrow_args = dict(arrowstyle="->")

# figure fraction
ax.annotate('figure fraction : 0, 0', xy=(0, 0),  xycoords='figure fraction', xytext=(20, 20), 
            textcoords='offset points', ha='left', va='bottom', bbox=bbox_args,
            arrowprops=arrow_args)
ax.annotate('figure fraction : 1, 1', xy=(1, 1),  xycoords='figure fraction', xytext=(-20, -10), 
            textcoords='offset points', ha='right', va='top', bbox=bbox_args,
            arrowprops=arrow_args)

# axes fraction
ax.annotate('axes fraction : 0, 0', xy=(0, 0), xycoords='axes fraction',
             xytext=(20, 20), textcoords='offset points',
             ha="left", va="bottom", bbox=bbox_args,
             arrowprops=arrow_args)
ax.annotate('axes fraction : 1, 1', xy=(1, 1), xycoords='axes fraction',
             xytext=(-20, -20), textcoords='offset points',
             ha="right", va="top", bbox=bbox_args,
             arrowprops=arrow_args)
```

[first plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q4y0N.png)

When no annotations are included i.e. just:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.axis([0, 10, 0, 10])
```

[second plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oD8wO.png)

Comment: What version of Matplotlib are you using? Running in the latest version (3.6.3), I find that the upper right figure fraction arrow does point right to the corner unlike your image.

Comment: Yes, I'm also running matplotlib 3.6.3. I'm using it with Spyder 5.4.2 IDE, with latest version of matplotlib-inline 0.1.6. The same issue exists whether I plot inline or not.